# how to write javascript:location.reload(true) method in @Html.ActionLink using mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I follow this format click on that actionlink that particular value go to database and fetch the values depending on that thing,that time, my total page will be refreshed, but I want refresh that particular part only, so I tried following this way

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "HomePage", new { CATEGORY = item.Name }, new { onclick = "javascript:location.reload(true)"})
```

But my whole page will be refreshed,what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:location.reload(true)` will always reload the whole page and there is nothing, you can do about this.

You need to use `@Ajax.ActionLink` and give it the id of the element that you want to replace with whatever comes from the server when your Action is invoked.